# Appium installation issue

Tags: node.js, automation, appium, mobile-app-testing

While installing Appium, I am having issue with plugins. To install them, I wrote:

appium server -ka 800 --use-plugins=execute-driver

It shows that plugin becoming (ACTIVE) but when I enter "appium" again, it shows no plugin activated.

Please help with this.

Comment: Could you give a bit more details in regards to exact commands u used and the output of them?

Comment: @TAEFED In CMD, I wrote: >appium. The result showed available drivers and plugins. Then it showed: "No plugins activated. Use the --use-plugins flag with names of plugins to activate".

I tried solving this with a yaml file but it seemed wrong. The plugins were:
- execute-driver@3.0.21
- images@2.1.8
- relaxed-caps@1.0.5
- universal-xml@1.0.15

Answer (score 0):

After you installed a plugin, for example with a command that looks like this:

```
appium plugin install --source=npm <plugin-package-on-npm>
```

You have to use the --use-plugins flag every time you start appium, so the command would be

```
appium --use-plugins=execute-driver
```

or

```
appium server -ka 800 --use-plugins=execute-driver
```